# iOS Upload file to Google Cloud Storage - getting 401: 'Login Required'

Tags: ios, google-cloud-storage, google-api-client

I am having trouble figuring out how to upload a file to a Public Access bucket to Cloud Storage.

1. I have set up a bucket and set it's ACLs to READ and WRITE for all users.
2. I have enabled the Cloud Storage JSON API and the Cloud Storage API.
3. I have created an API key for browser applications that allows any referrer.

Here is my code in Swift:

```
private lazy var googleServiceStorage:GTLServiceStorage = {
   var storage = GTLServiceStorage()
   storage.APIKey = "AIzaSy**********m8TPCM"
   storage.additionalHTTPHeaders = ["x-goog-project-id" : "159*******7"]
   return storage
   }()
}

public func uploadAssetToGoogle(resourcePath: String?) {
  if let _resourcePath = resourcePath {
      let fileHandle = NSFileHandle(forReadingAtPath: _resourcePath)
      let uploadParams = GTLUploadParameters(fileHandle: fileHandle, MIMEType: "video/mov")
      var storageObject = GTLStorageObject.object() as GTLStorageObject
      storageObject.name = "12345678"
      let query = GTLQueryStorage.queryForObjectsInsertWithObject(storageObject, bucket: "my-bucket", uploadParameters: uploadParams) as GTLQuery
      var ticket = googleServiceStorage.executeQuery(query) { ticket, object, error in
          if let _error = error {
              println("Error upload file: \(error.localizedDescription) : \(error.localizedFailureReason)")
              return
          }
          println("Upload succeeded")
      }
      ticket.uploadProgressBlock = {ticket, numberOfBytesRead, dataLength in
          println("Ticket: \(ticket)")
          NSLog("read %llu from %llu bytes", numberOfBytesRead, dataLength)
      }
  }
```

When I call this code I get the following output in the console:

```
mediaURL type: (Metatype) - file:///Users/Michael/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5895B7FA-41E7-4958-84FD-2C1043CA7CD7/data/Containers/Data/Application/2DD62539-E364-4BE0-A89C-E0DD2827D74B/tmp/trim.FCE68DAD-0FC6-4E2D-8C92-37055A02DD12.MOV

Ticket: GTLServiceTicket 0x7feed4860660: {service:<GTLServiceStorage: 0x7feed2cf9d90> devKey:AIzaSyBClcLHWtXzlBHb2VbATA1xIlUO0m8TPCM fetcher:GTMHTTPUploadFetcher 0x7feed4890fb0 (https://www.googleapis.com/upload/rpc?uploadType=resumable&prettyPrint=false) } 

2014-09-25 18:25:23.515 Beta[14917:1971326] read 202 from 29512 bytes 

Error upload file: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Login Required) : Optional("(Login Required)")
```

There is something I am missing, but I can't figure it out. If anyone can help me, it will save me a lot more hair.

Comment: Did you try "gcloud auth login" with the account associated with your project?

Answer (score 1):

For **Login Required** error message try with adding new bucket permission item

```
ENTITY = User, NAME = allUsers, ACCESS = Writer
```

> Please note: You have to use `Server API key` not `iOS API key`

For object upload, you can add `GTLStorageObjectAccessControl`

```
GTLStorageObjectAccessControl *objAccessControl = [GTLStorageObjectAccessControl new];
objAccessControl.entity = @"allUsers";
objAccessControl.email = @"xxxxxx-xxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
objAccessControl.role = @"OWNER";

GTLStorageObject *newObject = [GTLStorageObject object];
newObject.name = @"image.png";
newObject.acl = @[objAccessControl];
```

Than,

```
GTLQueryStorage *query = [GTLQueryStorage queryForObjectsInsertWithObject:newObject bucket:kBucketName uploadParameters:uploadParameters];
```