# Google Cloud Storage iOS - Without Authentication

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload or download files from *Google Cloud Storage* without authentication. I tried to use something similar to this https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/Introduction#Basics but didn't work.

```
let storage = GTLServiceStorage()
storage.additionalHTTPHeaders = ["x-goog-project-id":"my-project-id", "Content-Type": "application/json-rpc", "Accept": "application/json-rpc"]
storage.APIKey = "my-server-api-key"
storage.retryEnabled = true

// bucket
let bucket : GTLStorageBucket = GTLStorageBucket()
bucket.name = "my-bucket-name"

// this code doesn't matter is only for test the previous code
let query : GTLQueryStorage = GTLQueryStorage.queryForBucketsInsertWithObject(bucket, project: "my-project-id") as GTLQueryStorage
        self.storage.executeQuery(query, completionHandler: { (ticket : GTLServiceTicket!, object : AnyObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
            NSLog("Bucket: \(object)");
        })
```

When i tried the code above i get **"Login Required"** error, so i tried applying the following code before the code previous

```
auth.scope = kGTLAuthScopeStorageDevstorageFullControl
auth.clientID = "ios-client-id"
auth.clientSecret = "ios-client-secret"
auth.redirectURI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
storage.authorizer = auth // then set authorization to StorageService
```

But doesn't work. I get the error, keyName: **"Request"**

Please give me an example how to make it works or what i'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: any luck on this? I am still trying to find a seamless way for iOS to upload but it seams impossible!

Comment: Please check this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32442387/1767847)

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not sure this will solve your problem; all your variables are declared with the keyword `let` instead of `var`. Using the `let` keyword prevents any future changes to the object. It defines a constant. This prevents you from changing the object's properties the way you are doing now. You can find more info about this in the Swift [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID310).